# Trading view advanced chart v.26 not rendering chart with same data feed on version 25

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api

I have upgraded charting library from version 25 to version 26 but get bars methods get infinite loop and doesnot render chart in version 26.

```
        getBars(symbolInfo, resolution, periodParams) {
        let isAdjusted = document.getElementById('isAdjusted').value;
        const requestParams = {
            symbol: symbolInfo.ticker || '',
            resolution: resolution,
            StartDate: periodParams.from,
             EndDate: periodParams.to,
            from: "",
            isAdjust: isAdjusted,
            count: periodParams.countBack,

        };
        if (periodParams.countBack !== undefined) {
            requestParams.countback = periodParams.countBack;
        }
        if (symbolInfo.currency_code !== undefined) {
            requestParams.currencyCode = symbolInfo.currency_code;
        }
        if (symbolInfo.unit_id !== undefined) {
            requestParams.unitId = symbolInfo.unit_id;
        }
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this._requester.sendRequest(URL,  requestParams)
                .then((response) => {
                    if (response.s !== 'ok' && response.s !== 'no_data') {
                        reject(response.errmsg);
                        return;
                    }
                    const bars = [];
                    const meta = {
                        noData: false,
                    };
                    if (response.s === 'no_data') {
                        meta.noData = true;
                        meta.nextTime = response.nextTime;
                    }
                    else {
                       
                         
                            
                    resolve({
                        bars: bars,
                        meta: meta,
                    });
                    onHistoryCallback(bars, { noData: false });

                })
                .catch((reason) => {
                    const reasonString = getErrorMessage(reason);
                   
                });
        });
    }
```

There are any changes in the charting library so that the same datafeed doesnot render data in new version datafeed. The data feed is requesting data in infinite times and no chart is rendered